# How to show that V=W+{v in V | <v,w>=0 for all w in W}, where W is a subspace of V?

Tags: linear-algebra

How to show that $V = W + \{ v \in V \; | \; \langle v,w \rangle = 0\text{ for all }w \in W\}$, where $W$ is a subspace of $V$?
So this is the internal direct sum
I have no idea, we have to use some property of the inner product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $V$ is finite-dimensional:

First, we use the standard notation $$W^{\perp} = \{v \in V \mid \langle v,w\rangle = 0 \text{ for all }w \in W\}$$
Let $w_1,\ldots,w_k$ be an orthonormal basis for $W$. Then any $v \in V$ can be written in the form
$$v = w + u$$
where
$$w = \langle v,w_1 \rangle w_1 + \cdots + \langle v,w_k\rangle w_k$$
and
$$u = v - w$$
Note that for each $w_j$ we have
$$\langle u, w_j \rangle = \langle v, w_j \rangle - \langle w, w_j \rangle = \langle v, w_j \rangle - \langle v, w_j \rangle = 0$$
So $u$ is orthogonal to all of the $w_j$, hence orthogonal to $W$. This shows that $u \in W^{\perp}$, so $V \subseteq W + W^{\perp}$. Since the opposite containment obviously holds, we have $V = W + W^{\perp}$. To show that this is a direct sum, assume there is some $w \in W \cap W^{\perp}$. Then $w$ is orthogonal to itself, meaning $\langle w, w \rangle = 0$, which forces $w = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically consider the basis units of $V$. What is the span of the ones which are orthogonal with everything in $W $?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $V$ is finite-dimensional (otherwise, it's pretty messy, and I'm not even sure it holds).

Take an orthonormal basis $B_1$ of $W$, and extend it to an orthonormal basis $B_2$ of $V$ (this is done using Gram-Schmidt process). Then prove that $B_2\setminus B_1$ is a basis of $W^\perp=\left\{v\in V\middle|\forall w\in W:\left\langle v,w\right\rangle=0\right\}$ directly (it is obviously linearly independent; show that it spans $W^\perp$).